# Vector restored as ArrayList onRestoreInstanceState when Don't keep activities enabled

Tags: android

Simple test case 100% reproducible.
Try to enable "Don't keep activities" in developer options.

1 - Make as a member in your activity "Vector" (or any subclass of Vector).

2 - onSaveInstanceState put in bundle your vector member using "putSerializable"

3 - go to other activity (by pressing a button and opening new activity for example)

4 - In the new activity , press back button to finish it.

5 - Make shure to obtain your vector from savedInstanceState bundle that you recieve in onCreate.

6 - Crash !

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
```

Am I doing something wrong , or ist it broken in the platform ?

Comment: That indeed really weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All List will be rebuilded to ArrayList when passing by bundle.**

When transfer data between activities, all data implements Serializable in bundle will be written to byte stream, and recreate them in the new activity.

when you call bundle.getSerializable(), it will use [readValue()](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#2226) in [android.os.Parcel](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java) to get the values. In the source code of [Parcel.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#2226), it use [readArrayList()](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#readArrayList) method to create List when the object is subclass of List, it will not care whether it was Vector or others in the previous activity.

```
public final Object readValue(ClassLoader loader) {
    int type = readInt();

    switch (type) {
        case VAL_STRING:
            return readString();
            ...
        case VAL_LIST:
            return readArrayList(loader);
            ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the source code reference . Doesn't it looks like an unwanted behavior to you ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to sof. Here is the source code [Parcel.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#2226).